# one-to-one function inverse cardinality

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, inverse

Proof:

Prove that 
$f : A → B$ is one-to-one if and only if 
$|f^{-1}(b)| ≤ 1$ for all $b ∈ B$


I realize you must construct two proofs to prove both sides of the biconditional. I started first by assuming $f : A → B$ and trying to prove $|f^{-1}| ≤ 1$ for all $b ∈ B$. However, I thought it must be true that a function is bijective in order for the function to be invertible, so I got stumped immediately. Any tips?

Comment: $f^{-1}(b)=\{a\in A: f(a)=b\}$, which may be the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a critical portion of the problem statement. It should be something like

> *Problem:* Prove that $f: A \to B$ is one-to-one if and only if $|f^{-1}(\{b\})| \le 1$ for all $b\in B$.

You also have some confusion about the notation. The notation $f^{-1}$ is used to indicate *preimage* not *inverse*, which, as you note, may not exist. If $S$ is a subset of $B$, then $f^{-1}(S)$ is the subset of $A$ defined by $\{x\in A \mid f(x) \in S\}$, which may be empty in the case that $f$ does not map any points of $A$ into $S$.

Now, consult your definition of one-to-one and try to deduce that if $f$ is one-to-one, then there is at most $1$ point in the preimage of a given element $b\in B$. The converse direction is similar.

Comment: So, in order to prove the problem, you would use the statement $f^{-1}(b)$: { $a ∈ A$ | $f(a) = b$ }. Then, because the definition of one-to-one (expanded on in the proof), $b$ can equal only at most one value, thus concluding the cardinality is less than or equal to 1.